# NullReferenceException when accessing static properies of static class in C#

Tags: c#

In my efforts to add a vendor library to my code, I've added a library project to contain these dependencies.
After struggling with dependency conflicts for a while, because the vendor lib depends on some other version of system.* stuff then .NET does today. This I got to work by downgrading a few nuget packages.

Now whenever I try to access the vendor library, which uses `static classes` with `static properties`, I get a NullReferenceException on the vendor class names....

I'm at a loss here, because as far as I know static classes don't require an object, and thus will never be able to generate a NullReferenceException.

The vendor library class is some kind of data storage class.

Minimal example:

- Solution
- - Application project
- - Application module library
- - - Vendor library dll's.

Function I'm accessing:

```
public static class DataDisplayInfos {
    public static IEnumerable<MeasurementInfo> MeasurementInfoList { get; }
}
```

Where do I need to look to even start to troubleshoot this??

edit: the plot thickens... looks like it's an issue of the vendor library. Strange though that their example project does work...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'Ion.Sdk.Ddr.DataDisplayInfos' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: 
An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. 
This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. 
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at Ion.Sdk.Ddr.DataDisplayInfos.CreateInstanceBinaryStore(String assemblyLocation)
   at Ion.Sdk.Ddr.DataDisplayInfos..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Ion.Sdk.Ddr.DataDisplayInfos.get_MeasurementInfoList()
   at MetrelBlackBoxDevice.MI3325.FindMeasurement()
   at mvp_nullexcept.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Update:

Does it matter for dependencies if a project is compiled as class library or console project? I found that changing the project type to console application fixes the error, but makes it impossible to integrate in the parent project.

Comment: A static class doesn't require an object, that's correct. But `MeasurementInfoList` might be `null`.

Comment: Please show the code leading to the error. Are you sure that  `DataDisplayInfos.MeasurementInfoList` throws, not some other stuff you do with it (i.e. `DataDisplayInfos.MeasurementInfoList` is `null`)? Also maybe the library requires some initialization?

Comment: Also please post the full error.

Comment: @GuruStron How would I get a full error? VS only tells me a nullreference occured in [external code] ??

Comment: Assuming this is a closed-source library, you basically need to go to the vendor. It sounds like `CreateInstanceBinaryStore` has some dependency you're not aware of, or similar. I note that you're not *actually* getting a NullReferenceException though - you're getting a TypeInitializationException caused by NotSupportedException...